# Jason DeserializeObject giving error json reader exception for null string

Tags: c#, json

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize object received from REST API call. C# Class is like this

```
[JsonObject]
public class ResponseFromAPI
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "total")]
    public int Total;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "page")]
    public int Page;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "info")]
    public string Info;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "records")]
    public int NumberOfRecords;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public Data[] Data;
}
```

and the Data Class is as follows

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "values")]
    public string[] Values;
}
```

and the response from call I am getting in JSON string is like this

```
{
  "total": "1",
  "page": "1",
  "info": {},
  "records": "4",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "values": [
        "my.txt",
        "673",
        "/newFolder/my.txt",
        {}
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "values": [
        "test_file.txt",
        "9",
        "/newFolder/test_file.txt",
        {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The way I am deserialize response is as follows

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //TODO: Do something
    }

    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                responseToReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseFromAPI>(result);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I am receiving the results from the API but when it comes to deserialize the response the JsonConvert if throwing following error

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'info', line 4, position 14.
```

and when I comment out the Info field then I am getting

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'rows[0].cell[2]', line 8, position 98.
```

I checked stackoverflow other questions and googled it but I couldn't figure out what's wrong. Any suggestion on how to parse it correctly?

**UPDATE:** Corrected JSON

Comment: the json is not valid. Drop it into jsonlint.com and you'll see the error.

Comment: _"I couldn't figure out what's wrong"_ - It is literally telling you what is wrong: *"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'info', line 4, position 14."* Line 4, pos 14 is probably the "{" of `  "info": {},` because it expects a string, not object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is the `info` field that comes from the call as a object, not as a string, so you should change the `info` declaration to receive the object.

**EDIT:**

All `{}` that you have on your json are objects, so you need to make sure you can fix those first too

Comment: + this: `"values": [
        "test_file.txt",
        "9",
        "/newFolder/test_file.txt",
        {}
      ]` - last entry is also object instead of string.

Comment: I'd say, the json is corrupt, though.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But he is the one creating it and we don't have the code from where he does it

Comment: I am getting this JSON from a third party API but the suggestion resolved this error.